# If is_page elseif is_page not working like I want it to

Tags: php, templates

My code looks like this:

```
if (is_page('mounting-guides')):
  $guides = get_field('guide_pdfs');
elseif (is_page('user-manuals')):
  $guides = get_field('user_manual_pdfs');
elseif (is_page('cleaning-guides')):
  $guides = get_field('cleaning_guide_pdfs');
  if ($guides):
    // Do stuff
  endif;
```

Only the last elseif works. If I'm viewing the Mounting Guides or User Manuals page, nothing shows up. If I put my HTML in between the elseif's it works fine:

```
if (is_page('mounting-guides')):
  $guides = get_field('guide_pdfs');
  if ($guides):
    // Do stuff
  endif;
elseif (is_page('user-manuals')):
  $guides = get_field('user_manual_pdfs');
  if ($guides):
    // Do stuff
  endif;
elseif (is_page('cleaning-guides')):
  $guides = get_field('cleaning_guide_pdfs');
  if ($guides):
    // Do stuff
  endif;
```

Comment: Would it not make more sense to just use a single field named `pdfs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you take a look at the indentation of the code, which is correct, it should be pretty clear, why it is so.

```
if (is_page('mounting-guides')):
  $guides = get_field('guide_pdfs');
  // you don't do anything in this case
elseif (is_page('user-manuals')):
  $guides = get_field('user_manual_pdfs');
  // you don't do anything in this case
elseif (is_page('cleaning-guides')):
  $guides = get_field('cleaning_guide_pdfs');
  // this check is done only if you're on page 'cleaning-guides'
  if ($guides):
    // Do stuff
  endif;
```

If you want to "do stuff" for all of these pages, it should be like this:

```
if (is_page('mounting-guides')):
  $guides = get_field('guide_pdfs');
elseif (is_page('user-manuals')):
  $guides = get_field('user_manual_pdfs');
elseif (is_page('cleaning-guides')):
  $guides = get_field('cleaning_guide_pdfs');
endif;

if ($guides):
  // Do stuff
endif;
```

This way you set `$guides` if one of conditions is true, and after all of these checks you check if this variable is set and "do stuff".

Comment: Of course it was something that simple.... Thanks for the help

Comment: @sk03 simple problems are sometimes the hardest to notice.